How to identify the model of a Gemalto USB eToken?
The USB in the image below:
3 possible candidates (might not be conclusive list):

eIDAS USB token Gemalto SafeNet eToken 5110 CC (940)

USB token Gemalto SafeNet eToken 5110+

USB token Gemalto SafeNet eToken 5110+ FIPS (level 2)


The only piece of information is a 8 character alphanumeric code at the back +02BD512A which I assume is just identifiable information so I partially rewrote it.
Is there a way to get more information about it by reading it from the device itself?
The device Product ID PID_0620
The device Vendor ID VID_0529
I will email DigiCert about it but I am trying to solve this fast and don't have time to wait for a ticket reply.

If it says "Gemalto", then it's probably a 5110 and not 5110+, as the 'plus' version was introduced in 2022 and would say "Thales" (as Gemalto was acquired by them in 2019). Still, the 5110 had three versions (base, CC, FIPS) like in your list.
The model should be shown in the SafeNet Authentication Client, and reported through PKCS#11 as the name of the "smart card".
$ pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/pkcs11/libeToken.so --list-slots
Available slots:
Slot 0 (0x0): SafeNet eToken 5100 [eToken 5110 SC] 00 00
  token label        : etoken_ember
  token manufacturer : SafeNet, Inc.

It seems that for the base model it just says eToken 5110 SC.
You can also make a guess based on the supported ciphers (according to product brief for 5110+, as well as an older one for 5110) as that's really one of the biggest differences that are relevant when reusing an old token. (Most places that care about FIPS certification would generally order brand new tokens instead.)
$ pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/pkcs11/libeToken.so --list-mechanisms

For example (assuming 5110 and not 5110+), the base model supports SHA-1 while the FIPS model does not. The old product brief also says that the CC (Common Criteria) model runs a different firmware platform – IDPrime vs IDCore – which would also be shown by the SafeNet Authentication Client GUI.
02BD512A is the serial number.

Thank you. I forgot to add 1 helpful information. The USB is about 3.5 years old and yes it should be from Gemalto, as it is imprinted on the metal part. I am looking into the rest of your instructions now..

i know the 5110 product line will also detect as an Alladin card.  you would want to use the safenet application to give you all the details regarding the card.  This will tell you the applet version the card uses, which will be associated with a specific card.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
